# What causes a brushless motor to heat up?

Tags: motor, dc-motor

I have an RC airplane and I installed a motor on it. I want to guard against the motor burning up, and I have a few questions:

1. What causes waste heat in the motor? Is it purely proportional to the current used to drive it, or is it current and voltage? In other words, if I drive it at 10A/10V, will it get just as hot as if I drive it at 10A/20V?
2. Is there any way to estimate the maximum current/power the motor can safely take if this is not published by the manufacturer?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Resistive I^2R losses and to a lesser degree iron losses. Your two different drive voltages will depend on your driver, and motor. Is it spinning twice as fast on 20 V?

Comment: @winny yes it is.

Comment: There are rules of thumb that rely on motor mass. There's some amount of power per 100g of motor mass. But you can get a lot of power out of a motor by spinning it faster at the same torque (limited by bearings and heating from eddy losses) so you have to keep this in mind when trying to determine current. I forget what it is though. Look at a bunch of motors and do the calculation.

Comment: @DKNguyen basically I want to know whether I can run a motor more safely by using a higher voltage battery to lower the current at the same torque. That's why I'm wondering if heat is proportional to current or to power.

Comment: higher voltage will push more current through the motor windings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What causes the motor to burn up is mainly current (which is proportional to torque in DC motors). Running at higher RPMs means higher frequency currents running through the motor since the currents change direction more frequently through the windings due to commutation, and this induces eddy losses in the core which causes additional heating but this is normally small.

That's why high revving motors can put out much more power for the same size, because it's the current (proportional to torque) which burns the motor up, not the speed. But high-revving motors put out most of their power as speed and not so much as torque. Most applications tend to require more torque so you tend to need a gearbox to turn all that excess speed into necessary torque. Rewinding the motor to a lower kV also as a similar effect as a reduction gearbox. Of course, excessive speed will throw bearings and magnets and excessive voltage will fry the winding insulation.

A motor outputting a CONSTANT 1N-m of torque and spinning at 2000RPM will be double the output power, but have approximately the same heating as the same motor outputting a CONSTANT 1N-m of torque spinning at 1000RPM. I emphasize constant because changes in velocity will causes current spikes similar to a motor momentarily stalling and these currents will be higher with the higher RPM case since the running voltage will be higher, which means a larger difference between the supply voltage and BEMF whenever a dynamic speed change occurs. Also remember that a propeller's torque increases with speed.

You use a gearbox to make the propeller appear to the motor as a smaller (aka, higher RPM, lower torque) propeller which allows the motor to run cooler since what causes most of the heating is torque = current, not speed, while still maintaining the same power output. Rewinding the motor to a lower kV has a similar effect since it allows the motor to produce more torque with the same current, at the expense of lower RPM for the same voltage.

Generally, you cannot do what you are suggesting without a gearbox or without rewinding the motor for lower kV. On an airplane where propeller torque is increases with speed, increasing voltage increases RPM which increases torque which increases current which increases both heating and power output. But a gear box enables you to fiddle with that while keeping power output at the propeller the same by not having it spin any faster when more voltage applied to the motor, thus reducing torque on the motor and running at increased motor RPM instead.

You might potentially get away doing it with no gearbox (or without messing around with the ratios on your current gearbox) on something where the load torque is rather independent of the RPM, like a wheeled vehicle, as long as you accelerated slowly and smoothly to get around the dynamic speed change issue mentioned earlier.

You also cannot really run at a higher voltage and dial down the throttle. There are other factors at play. A motor running at 24V at 100% throttle is not the same as a motor running at 48V at 50% throttle. In a perfect world it does, but we don't live in one.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thank you!

Comment: By the way, you say "Rewinding the motor to a higher kV has a similar effect since it allows the motor to produce more torque with the same current, at the expense of lower RPM for the same voltage", but isn't higher KV -> higher RPM at a given voltage?

Comment: @StavrosKorokithakis Oh wait, you're right. I mean lower kV. I was thinking gear reduction ratios when I was typing that. It has been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

> What causes waste heat in the motor? Is it purely proportional to the
> current used to drive it, or is it current and voltage? In other
> words, if I drive it at 10A/10V, will it get just as hot as if I drive
> it at 10A/20V?

It is both. Current causes a loss in the winding resistance, commonly called 'copper loss', which is proportional to current squared. In your example the copper loss should be the same at both 10V and 20V.

Movement of the magnets causes loss in the core due to hysteresis - which is directly proportional to rpm, and eddy currents - which are proportional to rpm squared. At low rpm hysteresis loss dominates, but as rpm increases eddy current loss becomes more prominent. Finally there is bearing loss and 'windage' (air drag) which are generally less prominent. These losses are all combined into so-called 'iron' loss, which is equal to the power consumption (voltage x current) with no load.

You can expect the iron loss to be *at least* double at 20V compared to 10V.

The higher the voltage (and rpm) the closer the iron loss will get to the motor's rating, so (assuming the motor doesn't disintegrate first) there will be an upper voltage limit where the motor overheats even without any load. However it may get better cooling as a result of spinning faster due to the environment it is used in, extending the upper operating voltage compared to static running.

At the recommended operating voltage iron loss *should* be much less than copper loss at the rated current. Depending on the proportion of copper loss to iron loss and cooling, it may get barely hotter at 20 V than at 10 V, or it might get a lot hotter. However in most applications current is the dominant cause of heating.

> Is there any way to estimate the maximum current/power the motor can
> safely take if this is not published by the manufacturer?

You can compare it to a similar motor with known specs, but this will only provide a rough estimate. Comparing it to a similar motor that costs about the same might get you closer, because it generally costs more to make a more efficient motor.

Another way is to look at its usage. Since nobody will continue using a motor that burns out, it's a fairly safe bet that it can handle the voltage and current that people are putting through it *in a specific application*.

In the comments you mention a 1606 size motor that is rated for 22 amps 'max'. These are commonly used in racing drones that fly at relatively high speed (which provides excellent cooling) and the specified 'max' current will probably be the expected *peak* current. If your RC airplane also flies at high speed and airflow is directed through the motor then it should be able to handle a similar peak current *if* the specs are reasonable (often they are 'optimistic', particularly for cheap 'hobby' motors). The same motor in a slower model and/or without excellent cooling might need to be run at much lower current to avoid overheating.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense. I will generally be running it in similar conditions as a racing drone (lots of clean, cold air), but I'll be mindful and not exceed 20A just in case, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your first question was answered very well by @DKNguyen.

> Is there any way to estimate the maximum current/power the motor can safely take if this is not published by the manufacturer?

Yes and no.  All the RC motors pretty much use the same magnets, and the same construction.  So similar-weight motors have similar power-handling capabilities.  While I strongly suggest that your first choice to deal with a motor that doesn't have a current specification is to just buy a different one that *does*, your *second* choice is to weigh the motor, and compare its power handling capability (which is proportional to Kv times maximum current) to another cheap motor of roughly the same weight.  Or quicker yet, another cheap motor that's the same size.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Unfortunately this motor is a 1606, which is tiny, and there aren't many options at that size, so I couldn't get a different one with the same mount/KV. I will compare to another motor of the same size, though, thanks!

Comment: For the record, a similar motor has a max rating of 22A.